# Is there a DIP style chip I can use for a 74x245 and a 573 or 373?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dip

I'm looking into using a [W65C816S](http://www6.in.tum.de/pub/Main/TeachingWs2009Echtzeitsysteme/w65c816s.pdf) chip but to have full access to the address lines I need a 74x245 and a 573 or 373 chip. The only ones I've been able to find are SMD/SMT and not through hole. I'd like a DIP package so I can breadboard them. Are there DIP packaged chips around that I can use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

74LS245 is available in DIP package, so is 74HC245.
74HC573 and 373 are also available in DIP package. I have used a DIP 74HC574 (same as 573, but more convenient pinout for me) a couple of years ago.

Comment: Thank you, I've been digging around mouser but was looking in the wrong place.